# Trace and log all javascript functions calling tree/graph?

Tags: javascript, debugging, web

Is it possible to see all javascript function calls as a tree in any web debugger?

**UPDATE**

I mean debugger could remember each function call, from which other function it was done, also it could remember stack frame per each call and entire DOM snapshot.

**UPDATE 2**

The following page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Trace and log all javascript functions calling tree/graph?</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function init() {

        setDiv2("This div text was changed once");
        setDiv2("This div text was changed twice");

    };

    function setDiv2(text) {
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = text;
    }

    window.onload = init;

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Trace and log all javascript functions calling tree/graph?</h1>

    <p><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910262/trace-and-log-all-javascript-functions-calling-tree-graph">Stack Overflow Question #20910262</a></p>

    <div id="div1">This div will not changed</div>

    <div id="div2">This div text will change</div>

    <div>

    <h2>The call graph should be follows</h2>



    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Should give the following call graph

[image]

because `setDiv2()` function called twice.

In profiler's top-down view it is visible as

[image]

where `setDiv2()` function drawn once. This is good for profiling, but this is not call graph.

So the question persists.

**UPDATE 3**

Moreover, users should be able to step on each tree node and see the values of all variables and the state of entire DOM tree at the moment, represented by the node.

Comment: Please check the capabilities of the Google Chrome dev console

Comment: @JanDvorak I can't see functionality I am looking for.

Comment: Check the CPU profiler, specifically

Comment: @JanDvorak CPU profiler does not look as I would like. May be I mistake, but calls there looks like ordered by consumed time and grouped by function (as it should be in profiler). I need entire call graph, where calls are ordered in the order of execution and each function is represented the number of times it was called.

Comment: There are three views: top-down (function with its callees), bottom-up (function with its callers), or a flame graph (each function call is represented by a rectangle laying on its caller, with length representing time). Isn't the top-down view what you want?

Comment: @JanDvorak may be, can't judge so fast. Is it possible to start profiler exactly from scratch on loading new page?

Comment: How is it possible that this question has not yet been upvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Your need is obviously a custom profiler. Chrome JS profiler is a good handy tool. but i don't think that is correct tool for you. Also among the others Firebug or Safari profiler (webkits) won't do the job for you. So you need to develop your own custom profiler. since the others are only interested/targeted with CPU time profiling or memory usage profiling or CSS selectors.

You can modify `Object.prototype.constructor`. so all the global functions you have defined can have special profile method. or borrowed method via `Function.prototype.bind()` you can populate all the data you need from executions into a special data object. which can be like in a tree hierarchy. Here is the places to start a custom profiler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function 
and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Let us know if you can complete a custom profiler for javascript. it will be really useful tool for more people including me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Every browser has support to debug javascript code. You need to read about in specific browser you use. For example you can open developer tools in Mozilla Firefox by clicking Ctrl+Shift+K. In Internet Explorer you need to click F12 key. For Google Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I. After openning tools, you need to set up breakpoint at which you want to see stack trace, local variables and etc. After setting breakpoint you need to reload web-page, because when page is loaded all js is executed first time, and you can catch after loading, or make some event for catch breakpoint.

Comment: I see this in neither browser. All javascript debugging requires setting of breakpoints. I see no reason for this since web page is not a program, it not always executed.

Comment: I don't know where to set breakpoint and I don't want to know this. I need to track all DOM modifications from the very beginning to the very end.

Comment: Yes, page is not a program. But page have links or embedded script, which is executed after loading.

Comment: I have found extension for firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/ maybe it helps. Also you will need firebug.

Comment: so each execution should be catched and logged.

Answer (score 0):

try console.trace() in your setDiv2 function , in this case you will see the both tree calls in chrome console.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Trace and log all javascript functions calling tree/graph?</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function init() {

            setDiv2("This div text was changed once");
            setDiv2("This div text was changed twice");

        };

        function setDiv2(text) {
            document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = text;
            console.trace()
        }

        window.onload = init;

    </script>

</head>
.....
```

Comment: I have no access to code. I need general solution for third party pages.